# Possibilities for the Jordan normal form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-analysis, jordan-normal-form

I need to show: 
 
How many possibilities for the Jordan normal form (up to order of the Jordan blocks on the diagonals) there are for matrices $B \in M_5 (\mathbb C) $ with $x_B(\lambda)=-(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda-3)^3$

What I already have:
 
The Eigenvalues are  $2 $ and  $3 $.
 
The Eigenvalue  $2 $ has the algebraic multiplicity 2  and the geometric  multiplicity $ 2  $ or  $1 $. 
 
The Eigenvalue  $3 $ has the algebraic multiplicity 3 and the geometric  multiplicity $ 3 $ or  $ $2 or  $1 $.

So I tried showing all the possibilites with:

1) $diag (J_1 (2), J_1 (2), J_1(3), J_1(3), J_1(3))$

2) $diag (J_2 (2), J_1(3), J_1(3), J_1(3))$

3) $diag (J_2 (2), J_3(3))$

4) $diag (J_1 (2), J_1 (2), J_3(3))$

5)$ diag (J_2 (2), J_2(3), J_1(3))$

6) $diag (J_1 (2), J_1 (2), J_2(3), J_1(3))$

I am not sure if this is right though..

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $\chi_B(\lambda)=-(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda-3)^3$?

Comment: Correct... Sry my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Let $\DeclareMathOperator{am}{am}\am_B(\lambda)$ and $\DeclareMathOperator{gm}{gm}\gm_B(\lambda)$ denote the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$ respectively. Then the table of eigenvalues of $B$ along with their algebraic multiplicities and possible geometric multiplicities is
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\lambda & \am_B(\lambda) & \gm_B(\lambda) \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 1,2 \\
3 & 3 & 1,2,3
\end{array}
$$
There are thus six possible combinations of geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues of $B$. These six possible combinations yield exactly the six Jordan forms you have listed.

Note, however, that in general a choice of geometric multiplicities can yield more than one possible Jordan form. For example, both
\begin{align*}
J_2(\lambda)\oplus J_2(\lambda) && J_3(\lambda)\oplus J_1(\lambda)
\end{align*}
have characteristic polynomial $\chi(t)=(t-\lambda)^4$ and hence have exactly one eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity two.